# Robust matching of values to a uniform sequence

Tags: algorithms, pattern-matching

I have a sequence of $N$ real numbers $X_i$ that are deemed to be equally spaced. $N$ is small (say $10$ to $20$).

Two problems can arise:

- the spacing isn't perfectly uniform, it can vary in a smooth way, possibly causing a shift of, say up to $2$ points compared to the ideal arrangement;
- there can be a few (say up to $3$) missing or extra points.

Do you have suggestions on how to efficiently number the points to get a "best correspondence" ?

In the example figure, the given positions are compared to the ideal ones (in blue). There is a displaced point ($5$) and a missing one ($9$). The expected output of the algorithm is $(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,10,11)$. Don't be confused by the plot, it is a 1D problem, all points should be projected on the vertical axis.

[image]

A possible solution could be to fit a low order polynomial, say cubic, and try different hypothesis of missing or extra points (like when computing a string edit distance), but that will be time consuming. I am looking for a simpler solution.

Note that just associating the points to their nearest ideal neighbor can fail because of the shift (in the given example, $5$ is closer to the ideal $4$ than to the ideal $5$).

**Update**:

The $x_i$'s are sorted. Because of possible insertions/deletions, the desired number of correspondences is a given $M$ which can differ from $N$. When $N<M$, there will be associations to "none".

For convenience you can assume the values to have been normalized to the range $[0,M-1]$, so that the ideal sequence is just given by $i$.

I acknowledge that the problem is no perfectly specified, as there can be ambiguous cases: for instance, when the given points are uniformly spaced but one is missing, there are several equally good assignments.

Comment: Still, assigning the points to their nearest ideal neighbour would be a great first step. In your example case, that would leave you with just one double assignment, which only requires a single binary decision whether to move the extra point to the nearest free slot either on the left or on the right -- all you need is a reasonable quality measure for assignments to make those decisions. (In the example case there isn't even the option of moving it to the other side since there's no free slot there, so the correct outcome would be determined without having to make any decisions at all.)

Comment: @joriki: the nearest ideal neighbor is easily found by rounding the normalized value (see the Update). But this may not be a good choice when the shift is large (when there are no insertions/deletions, the one-to-one assignment can be better than the nearest-neighbor). Maybe the solution lies in arbitrating the discrepancies between natural numbering and nearest neighbor.

Comment: It seems that perhaps I didn't get across what I meant. It's clear that simply using the nearest-neighbour assignment won't always be a good choice. My point was that the steps and decisions you need in order to get from the nearest-neighbour assignment to a better assignment (better according to some measure you can define, which may or may not include injectivity) are quite simple (at least nowhere near as complicated as fitting polynomials through all possible candidate configurations with missing or extra points).

Comment: @joriki: possibly a measure of "non-uniformity" based for instance on comparing the distances between successive point pairs.

Answer (score 1):

**My attempt:** Let $(x_i)$ be the sequence of points you have. I would first order this sequence (if it is not ordered yet). Now I would do something like:

```
xs // list of given x_i, ordered
ys // final list

for i in 0 ... len(xs):
    if i == 0:
         ys[0] = round(xs[i])
    else:  
         ys[i] = max( round(xs[i]), ys[i-1]+1 )
    endif
endfor
```

So the final sequence $(y_i)$ is defined recursively via

$$\begin{align} y_0 & = \operatorname{round}(x_0) \\ y_{n+1} &= \max\{ \operatorname{round}(x_{n+1}), y_n + 1 \}\end{align}$$

From this you might find a more memory-efficient or time-efficient algorithm. Because you have to go over the (ordered) sequence $x_i$ only once the algorithm above needs time linear to the length of $(x_i)$.

Comment: Interesting, thanks. Memory/time efficiency is not the prime consideration, given the small value of $N$. $O(N^2)$ would remain acceptable, preferably not $O(N^3)$. Your approach is interesting, but it seems to be "forward only", if you see what I mean.

Answer (score 0):

My own attempt:

In the ideal sequence, the distance between consecutive points is $1$. When the density increases or decreases locally, it changes to $1\pm\epsilon$. When a point is displaced, the distance becomes $1-\epsilon$ on a side and $1+\epsilon$ on the other. When one or more point is missing, the distance jumps to about $2,3\cdots$ When one or more extra points are inserted, at least one of the distances drops below $0.5$. So we are looking for evident outliers.

So the idea is to detect distances below $1-\alpha$ and above $1+\beta$, for two well chosen thresholds, and

- discard one of the endpoints of the small intervals. To decide which endpoint, we can choose the endpoint that has the closest (other) neighbor;
- insert dummy points in the large intervals; to decide then number of points to be inserted, we can round the distance to the next integer.

When all "abnormal" distances have been processed, we end up with $N$ points left. If $N=M$, we are fine, otherwise the sequence is declared "unmatchable".

As a variant, we can also process the abnormal intervals by decreasing order of abnormality, until we obtain $M$ points.

As another variant, we can make the method adaptive by estimating the local density, and relating the distances to the local estimate. A robust estimator could be the median of, say 5 or 7 distances in a sliding window or at a few points. The local estimator can be interpolated or approximated by fitting a low degree polynomial.